# Is there a simpler way to get object from groupby and putting in dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So my dataframe looks like this:
[image: dataframe snapshot]
I am trying to find a simpler way to get the objects from a Groupby and then putting it in a dictionary.
I had to obtain the index and then do a for loop to get the exact string of each row in Product.

More details if needed:
My goal was to find duplicate Order ID and then take the products from the column and add to dictionary with:

- **key** = Product
- **value** = no of times the Product is found to be ordered together

(I am not looking for ways to optimize finding duplicates, i know I could use `df.duplicated` )

Code:

```
for date, df in df1.groupby('Order Date'):
    
    if  df.Product.count() > 1:

        indice = df.Product.index
        for data in indice:
            product = df.loc[data].at['Product']
            #update dictionary counter
            product_dict[product] = product_dict.get(product) + 1
      
    else:
        continue
```

for ease you can use this df instead. I listed as dictionary:

```
{'Order ID': ['147268', '148041', '149343', '149964', '149350', '141732', '149620', '142451', '146039', '143498', '141316', '144804', '144804', '145270', '142789'],
 'Product': ['Wired Headphones', 'USB-C Charging Cable', 'Apple Airpods Headphones', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 'USB-C Charging Cable', 'iPhone', 'Lightning Charging Cable', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', '34in Ultrawide Monitor', 'AA Batteries (4-pack)', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 'Wired Headphones', 'iPhone', 'Google Phone', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)']}
```

**The expected output:**

{'Wired Headphones': 8090, 'USB-C Charging Cable': 9425, 'Apple Airpods Headphones': 6374, 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)': 8266, 'iPhone': 3663, 'Lightning Charging Cable': 9074, '34in Ultrawide Monitor': 2500, 'AA Batteries (4-pack)': 8167, 'Google Phone': 3091, 'Macbook Pro Laptop': 1878, 'ThinkPad Laptop': 1605, '27in FHD Monitor': 3010, 'Bose SoundSport Headphones': 5459, 'Flatscreen TV': 1827, '27in 4K Gaming Monitor': 2457, 'LG Dryer': 257, '20in Monitor': 1635, 'LG Washing Machine': 268, 'Vareebadd Phone': 1120}

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow! Please don’t post the images of the data as we can’t test them.  Instead, post a sample of the DataFrame (`df`) and the expected output directly inside a code block.  A good way is to share the outputs of `print(df.to_dict(orient=‘list’))` along with `print(df)`. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response and welcome.
I reduced my dataframe to a smaller one as the original one is  too big to paste as dict.

Comment: Thanks, it's better now! But the expected output would also help to confirm if I understood correctly the problem. Does my answer produce the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# number of products per order 
prods_per_order = df.groupby(['Order ID'])["Product"].transform("count")

res = ( 
    df.loc[prods_per_order > 1, "Product"]   # Select only the products that were ordered together with another(s) product(s)
      .value_counts()      # count how many times were per product 
      .to_dict()           # convert the result to a dict 
)
```

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order ID': ['147268', '148041', '149343', '149964', '149350', 
                 '141732', '149620', '142451', '146039', '143498', 
                 '141316', '144804', '144804', '145270', '142789'],
     'Product': ['Wired Headphones', 'USB-C Charging Cable', 'Apple Airpods Headphones', 
                 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 'USB-C Charging Cable', 'iPhone', 
                 'Lightning Charging Cable', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', '34in Ultrawide Monitor', 
                 'AA Batteries (4-pack)', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 'Wired Headphones', 
                 'iPhone', 'Google Phone', 'AAA Batteries (4-pack)']
})

df = df.sort_values(['Order ID', 'Product'])
```

```
>>> df 

   Order ID                   Product
10   141316    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
5    141732                    iPhone
7    142451    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
14   142789    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
9    143498     AA Batteries (4-pack)
11   144804          Wired Headphones  # <-- Note that only these two products
12   144804                    iPhone  # <--    were ordered together 
13   145270              Google Phone
8    146039    34in Ultrawide Monitor
0    147268          Wired Headphones
1    148041      USB-C Charging Cable
2    149343  Apple Airpods Headphones
4    149350      USB-C Charging Cable
6    149620  Lightning Charging Cable
3    149964    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
```

**Output**

```
>>> res

{'iPhone': 1, 'Wired Headphones': 1}
```

Comment: Yes that is almost what I wanted, so basically for the dictionary it would be :

{ Product: <Product count with a shared Order ID>}
 
So whenever in df there is a repeated Order ID and 2 different products, it means these products were bought together. hence I would add to dictionary.
You can see my desired output, i added it now. 
Thanks

Comment: For more clarification from prev comment:   I would add both products to the dictionary e.g. If earphones had ID 10179 and iphone had 10179,  thus they were bought together. So in my dictoinary iphone counter will go up and earphone counter will go up.

Comment: Also Harry, if you could explain your single line that would be helpful:
res = df2.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].value_counts().loc[lambda counts: counts > 1].to_dict()
so from what I understand so far: we get the count of unique values from value counts, and is this value being used as an argument in lambda  function? And lamda returns a boolean?

Comment: @Sleepelite I think I finally understood what you want. I was misinterpreting the question. I will update my answer with the correct solution soon!

Comment: @Sleepelite All done! See if it produces the correct output. If you don't understand the code, let me know!

Comment: Wow, thanks @HarryPlotter, that was exactly what I needed and explained perfectly!

Comment: @Sleepelite You're welcome! I'm glad it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand, but this seems to do what you are trying to achieve by using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

mask = (
    df.groupby(["Order Date", "Order ID"], sort=False)["Product"]
      .transform("count")
      .gt(1)
)
product_dict = Counter(df.loc[mask, "Product"])
```

Result for the slightly modified sample dataframe (added an `Order Date` column)

```
   Order Date Order ID                   Product
0  2021-11-11   147268          Wired Headphones
1  2021-11-11   148041      USB-C Charging Cable
2  2021-11-11   149343  Apple Airpods Headphones
3  2021-11-11   149964    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
4  2021-11-11   149350      USB-C Charging Cable
5  2021-11-12   141732                    iPhone
6  2021-11-12   149620  Lightning Charging Cable
7  2021-11-12   142451    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
8  2021-11-12   146039    34in Ultrawide Monitor
9  2021-11-12   143498     AA Batteries (4-pack)
10 2021-11-12   141316    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
11 2021-11-12   144804          Wired Headphones
12 2021-11-12   144804                    iPhone
13 2021-11-12   145270              Google Phone
14 2021-11-12   142789    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
```

is

```
Counter({'Wired Headphones': 1, 'iPhone': 1})
```

Maybe it's enough to `groupby` over `Order ID`, but since you are grouping over `Order Date` I suspect it isn't.

Comment: So basically the dictionary I wanted is : { Product: <Product count with a shared Order ID>} So whenever in df there is a repeated Order ID and 2 different products, it means these products were bought together. hence I would add to dictionary. You can see my desired output, i added it now. Thanks

Comment: I realized your code gives me the output I needed as well, I didnt understood the code right away so didnt realize. Thanks a lot for your help Timus.